# How to set the brand logo in Bootstrap 4 navbar to the left edge?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a logo as shown below.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-primary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">START</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Bootstrap adds a piece of padding on the left resulting in the following offset from the edge.

[image]

Since our logo is a cut off circle, we want it to be placed precisely at the edge to create illusion of a real circle but sticking outside of the browser. I've tried to set a negative margin on the left side but it only moved the image, still retaining the weird edge as shown below.

```
<img class="navbar-brand" src="logo.png" alt="logo" style="margin-left: 0px;">
```

[image]

What can I do about it?

Comment: it's not the image you should put margin as zero but the nav itself and/or the div that's it inside of, along with `!important` if used inside a separate css file and/or inline. The `body` could also be at play here.

Comment: Can you provide a real working example? (jsfiddle/snippet/codepen)

Comment: you've an answer below with actual code. I only said what needed to be done, "in words". I like to make people think and learn ;-) Edit: however, their logo in the fiddle doesn't seem to be flushed to the left, unless that's what you want. 2nd edit: they removed their fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9t20dmLk/

Comment: use `row` instead of `container-fluid`. these both have opposite margins. https://jsfiddle.net/gsb3ohd2/

Comment: @Banzay I like your suggestion the best because it's least intrusive on the styling and structure. Would you mind posting it as a reply so it can get accepted, please? Also, I have two follow-up questions but we can take that once you repost your comment, OK?

Comment: I repost it as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `row` instead of `container-fluid`. these two have opposite margins.

https://jsfiddle.net/gsb3ohd2/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-primary">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">START</a></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: On the navbar, we also have a button and a search box that are supposed to be placed to the right. When the class was *container-fluid*, those elements were on the right. Now, that I've changed to *row*, as you suggested, everything seems to have floated to the left. Any ideas how to approach it? And question #2 - is the class *row* supposed to be used this way (in the navbar, I mean)?

Comment: concerning first issue - could you give a link to fiddle? I'm not so familiar with BS-4, then it's better to look at.

Comment: you can use `float-xs-right` class here `<ul class="nav navbar-nav float-xs-right">`

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. On my screen, the stuff are pushed all to the left. In the fiddle (copied exact the same code) it works! I hate when this happens... I already have the *float-xs-right* style. It should work... Take a look at [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/twjdodj1/). It behaves on my computer as if I had *float-xs-left*... What can be the problem?

Comment: it seems that nav menu floats left by default. I tested -  `float-xs-right` works as intended. I thought - I can propose to you one more solution for your question - without change markup, but minimal styling css only.

Comment: `.navbar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
.navbar ul {
  margin-left: 40px;
}`

Comment: In fact, I prefer to change the markup. CSS is brought from the precompiled CSS based on SASS and I fear that when we start updating, the settings might get lost and I'll be a very unhappy programmer. I asked the question [in a separate post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309102/style-for-floting-right-in-bootstrap-4-doesnt-work) because this one is accepted as you did provide an answer to this question already.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the left padding of `.navbar-brand` and `.container-fluid.navbar-container`(you don't want to override the styles of `.container-fluid`, so add a new class to it).

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-primary">
  <div class="container-fluid navbar-container">
    <img class="navbar-brand" src="logo.png" alt="logo">
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.container-fluid.navbar-container, .navbar-brand {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9t20dmLk/1/

Comment: Would you say that it's better to tamper with the styles as you suggest or is it a neat approach to use a predefined class *row* as Banzay shows?

Comment: You can do it either way. Also note that the class `navbar-brand` has padding-left of `15px` in bootstrap 3.3.7(which I had included in my fiddle). It is always good to know which element has the margin/padding set to it. Personally, I would go with Bazay's solution :)