# Style for floating right in Bootstrap 4 doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/dy7bf4ww/), I can see that the search box is floated right, as supposed to. On my screen, it's not. In fact, it behaves as if I put the style to be *float-xs-left* or simply left the floating related styling out.

Not sure how to troubleshoot it, since I can't reproduce the problem. I've checked everything I could thing of on my system but it's a navbar, a top level component so there's very little that can be screwed up.

```
<form class="form-inline float-xs-right">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Stuff">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Click</button>
</form>
```

Before, I had the logo in div of class *container-fluid* and it was working as supposed to (pushing the stuff to the right). However, I needed to go for *row* for [other reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308731/how-to-set-the-brand-logo-in-bootstrap-4-navbar-to-the-left-edge), hence landing in to this problem.

Does anybody recognize the misbehavior? What can I do to investigate further?

Comment: did you try `Ctrl+Shift+I` to inspect what style affects on the form?

Comment: Which browser did you check with? What do you mean by "On my screen, it's not"?

Comment: @Dekel IE, FF and Cr. It's something with the site **except** the navbar, since it works on the fiddle. I'm just stuck at what more to investigate and was hoping for something insightful. :)

Comment: Any chance to get a link to the site?

Comment: @Dekel I would love to but it's *locahost* at the moment. And it's going to be on the intranet as it deals with money and investigations... I'm starting to suspect that I'll have to get back to the version prior the change to style *row*. Darn...

Comment: Can you copy&paste the html you see in your browser to a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Banzay It says that it's from bootstrap-flex and the name is correct. It adds style *float-xs-right {float: right !important;}*... There's something weird going on. When I added *<div class="alert alert-success">
Well done!</div>*, the box is green but the text is red! What the duck?! (typo intended)

Comment: @Dekel Sure thing, mate. [It's already there](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/twjdodj1/). Ugly and nasty and in a wrong language - real working version, hehe.

Comment: Does your `html` starts with the `<nav` element?

Comment: Nope. It starts with *<template>* because we work with Vue. But as far I could tell, there's nothing other than just a div (unstyled) between that and the outer HTML tag. And please remember that it did behave properly when I was using *container-fluid*.

Comment: right click (in chrome/firefox) on one of the elements, inspect it, find the `html` element, right click, copy->copy outerHTML, paste this into the jsfiddle :)

Comment: @Dekel Please view [this attrocity](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/u9oqmk95/). I do appreciate the help. Sorry for the time it took - I was fighting BitBucket and a bunch of other weird things that happened all at once.

Comment: Many of the resources are missing there. Can you please add them as well? `tether.css`, `bootstrap` (several files) and more... I'm not sure which of them cause the problem, but it is probably one of them.

Comment: @Dekel I've added all the packages as external resource and copied in CSS in the separate window. It still seems to work on the jsFiddle. Crap... Perhaps it's time to let it go and accept that the fluid container needs to be used creating that weird spacing on the left (the original issue)?

Comment: You can see that those external resources don't really work: https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/u9oqmk95/tether.css Can you zip all of them so I can download?

Comment: @Dekel 
[Here's a ZIP](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v4.0.0-alpha.5/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.5-dist.zip) with Bootstrap and [here's a ZIP](http://github.com/HubSpot/tether/archive/v1.3.3.zip) with Thether. (Apparently Bootstrap recommens Thether for popovers, now.)

Comment: Great, now I have it working (float to the left) so I can find a solution for you :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten did you check the answer?

Comment: @Dekel Actually, I'm about to do it right now. I've found another thing with the menus that I got stuck on and made me lose track of this one. Thanks for poking me. I'm working with several issues simultaneously to get everything resolved today. I'll get back to you in 15 minutes. Awesome agility on your part, I must admit.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: btw, it will also be nice to see the final solution (if you didn't choose the one I provided)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the combination of the new bootstrap's grid system (which is based on `flex`) and the `float-right` that you wanted for the logo.

You can solve this by using

```
.navbar .row .form-inline.float-xs-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: The only drawback to this approach I can see is that the rest of the elements are placed behind others (since the positioning is killed by our custom class and Bootstrap keeps the margin without respect to the absolutely positioned ones). In my opinion, it's something wrong with the way the margin is eating the logo. When I push it to the left, I want it to be seen in its entirety still. Well, Merry Christmas or Happy Holidays depending on your religious predisposition. I owe you a pizza if you're ever in Stockholm.

Comment: Happy Hanukkah here in Israel :) Thanks! I agree with that comment. Don't have plans for Stockholm, but will keep it in my mind and update you when I'm there :)

Comment: The final solution was to declare a class targeting a specific ID and apply what you said (except *right: 10px* because I needed some margin there). It seemed the least intrusive on Booty.

Comment: Great to know :) Thanks for sharing!